# How to make skills assessment fair?

Tags: resume, career-development, career-switch, skills

I have been experiencing a hard time tracking my work records. This leads to difficulties in assessing my skills over the time by myself, by current employer, or prospective employers.

Over the time, my coworkers and I tend to forget about each other work records.
Additionally, my coworkers or I will eventually move on to new workplace.
This makes skills assessment of oneself or each other hard to be fair.

My questions are:

**1. Should I keep work records in proper form in order to support fair skills assessment by myself or by others ? Which form is it ?**

**2. Is there any software solution for work records tracking ?**

**3. Is fair and transparent work records important for finding new jobs inside or outside organization ?**

Comment: Your "skills overtime" ? so those skills you used when doing overtime?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid bias? A resume is a way of advertising yourself to a company, so in some sense it should be biased. It must be factual but ultimately should still explain "here is why you should hire me."

Comment: @SolarMike it's more like "over the time period" sort of thing. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh so “overtime” is not the same as "over time", using the correct words does help clarity...

Comment: @SolarMike absolutely, I edited to clarify.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I commented so the OP would improve the question, that way the original meaning is kept intact without a third party having to guess...

Answer (score 2):

> *1. How can I overcome the issues of tracking work records in biased ways ?*

Simple, do not use the CV as a *tracking tool or document*. You can keep a separate record-book of the work experience with all the details you have, but keep the CV short and sweet, to the point of interest of the prospective employer.

> *2. How do I know my skills match requirements of prospect companies ? and vice versa, how do prospect companies know my skills match their requirements ?*

From the job description and knowledge of your skillsets. Prospective employers will get to know you first from the CV and the cover letter and at a latter stage, through the interview process.

Remember: Whatever you put into your CV, for a particular application, your perspective employer is going to see and know you in that light. And yes, it's not uncommon to have multiple CVs highlighting different areas of your work and skillset, based on the job or role (position) you're applying for.

Comment: +1 for multiple CVs.  A CV is a tool in the application process and should be shaped by the position you are applying for

Comment: @DaveGremlin `:%s/should/must/g`. :)

Answer (score 0):

The records are biased only if you make them look biased. A properly written CV will not have this problem.

A properly written CV will state information like this:

- personal details;
- places of education, degrees, time frame of the enrollment, achievements - shown as numbers
- jobs: companies, time frame for each job, responsibilities, difficulties, descriptions of solutions - using numbers instead of qualifiers;
- others: using (as much as possible) numbers, brand names, names of technologies...

If you do that, you will have a clear record with (almost) no bias.

On the other hand, if you start writing stories, using words like many, a lot, never... then yes, it may become biased a lot: what is "many" to you, might be "just a few" for somebody else.